# C# Silverlight Forum component

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls, forum

Has anyone encountered such a beastie? I'm thinking about a tree-like display, database, login and registration etc. Ideally ready to bake as time is short.

Ideally BSD or similar license but if neccessary might persuade the beancounters to cough up some beans.

Alternatively if anyone is interested in creating something please comment

Thanks

G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any Silverlight Forum components in my travels around the internet. I think you might be stuck rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app now in Silverlight made by Myer check this out,

http://www.mher.info/blog/?p=136

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

we have opened a program to help people receive components they have big need of, mainly we concentrate now on Silverlight and WPF.

you can check more information here http://fpscomponents.com/Post.aspx?id=19